# Can the Geth password be cracked

Tags: security, password

When we create a new user in Geth, we need to enter a password. When initiating transactions in the future, you also need to use this password to unlock the account first. I want to know where the password is stored on Geth, is it possible to crack this password?

Hope you can give me a little help, thanks!

Comment: Ethereum does not have passwords. Ethereum has only private keys. Only services and applications using Ethereum has passwords. The question you have is not about Ethereum generally, but specific to some software. I suggest you edit your question and add the name of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have updated my question.

Comment: Here is a service that helps you to crack geth passwords, or wallet recovery https://keychainx.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a password which you give when you create a wallet in your local machine. The password has actually very little to do with Ethereum.

When you create a wallet (an account) a private key is generated. That private key is the most important secret you have - anyone with that private key has full access to your wallet and its assets. So the software you use stores the private key in your hard drive and encrypts it with a password. Whenever you want to use the private key for transactions you first have to provide the password to decrypt the private key.

If the password is leaked it's not a big issue as long as nobody gets access to your hard drive.

Comment: Get it! Thank you very much for your help. I have received your help several times and benefited a lot. But recently I still have a question about the security of the private blockchain, I wonder if you can give me some advice？

Comment: Just post a new question and someone will probably help. Or search the existing questions

Comment: OK. Thanks! I will try to find the similar question.